# How to create a new owl:DatatypeProperty and add it at an exisisting ontology with owl api?

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

I' d like to create a new owl:DatatypeProperty like this:

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://sisinflab.poliba.it/semanticweb/ontologies/architecturalpatterns#extensibilityRate">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">extensibilityRate</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:range>
        <rdfs:Datatype>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdfs:Datatype>
                    <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>
                    <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">0</xsd:minInclusive>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </owl:withRestrictions>
                </rdfs:Datatype>
                <rdfs:Datatype>
                    <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>
                    <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <xsd:maxInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">4</xsd:maxInclusive>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </owl:withRestrictions>
                </rdfs:Datatype>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </rdfs:Datatype>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

and add it to my owl ontology, but I can't do it. Any suggestions?

I'm trying to follow the example [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) (row 235); Eclipse does not show compile or running errors, but the ontology is not updated.

Comment: I' trying to follow example of documentation at link [link](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) (row 235); Eclipse don' t show compile or running errors, but there isn' t what I would in my ontology.

Answer (score 0):

The test method that you pointed at has the following:

```
manager.saveOntology(ontology, new StreamDocumentTarget(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
```

Here the ontology is written to a byte array that's held in memory, so no changes will be saved to file. For the original file to be modified, you need to remove the second argument and just use

```
manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```

If the ontology was created from code and never saved before, you'll have to pass an actual file output stream instead (so that the file can be created and populated.